# Renaming a form in Visual C++

Tags: c++, forms

I start Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I chose to start a new project on the Welcome Page. Ofcourse my preferred language is Visual C++ and I'm chosing to begin a Windows Forms Application. I give up a name like Calculator for this one. I do not touch the other options on this dialog. The project gets created and a new Form1.h is automatically added to the project, and a Form1.resX is also added. Because 'Form1' is useless to me, I'dd like to rename it to something more VB6 style, like "frmMain.h". So I right click the Form and simply chose "Rename". After accepting my new name, the necessary changes seem to be occuring. *first impression* But now, when I try to build this project, It gives a BUILD FAILED. When I look into my files.. Form1 is still mentioned..

So my question is: How do you actually/OFFICIALLY rename Forms?

I've been reading a lot about this and mostly the answer is to delete the form, and re add a new with the right name.. I've heard also that VS asks to rename all references to it, but that doesn't show up to me. Some other people say, you have to use the quick replace function, and rename all references to this class and its file.. This is not a good way to me.. Or is it really the standard procedure?

I have programming experience in C++ and I know about classes and polymorfism and so on. But this is one of the simplest things that keeps me annoying!

Comment: Seriously, to make your first steps with WinForms, I strongly recommend to choose C#, even when you learned C++ in the past. What you were trying is to use the language "C++/CLI" (since native C++ cannot use WinForms directly), which is much better understood when you have done C# *and* native C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using VC++.NET to create .NET applications (Windows Form in your case). I must warn you that VS is not very friendly for VC (refactoring, renaming, and little intellisense).

In this case, you renamed the form which will make VS also rename the Form1.resX, but it will not rename the class. It will do it if in C# or VB.NET. Just open the .h file and rename the class itself to match the name of the file.

You also need to update the main .cpp file where "main" resides, and update the Application::Run(gcnew Form1()); in there as well include the "#include".

A solution replace will work (Ctrl+Shift+H), but be careful with this.

Comment: Yup.  Otherwise no different from renaming classes in C++.

Answer (score 0):

click on the form -> properties -> text (usually named as Form1) -> change it.

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.